# OpenAL - sources don't mute completely beyond maximum distance

Tags: iphone, ios, openal

my sources change in volume nicely between the reference distance and the maximum distance. however - all sources beyond the maximum distance i can hear too - theyr volume is low but they're not completely muted.

how to make sure that they get completely muted if they're farther away than the maximum distance?

Platform is iOS.

Comment: Which attenuation model are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the [specification](http://connect.creativelabs.com/openal/Documentation/OpenAL%201.1%20Specification.htm#_Toc199835864)? Try configuring attenuation models to your needs. Make sure AL_MIN_GAIN is zero.